# Stripping strings from a text file in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have text that I need to manually convert from XML as it seems it does not work with PHPs xml tools very well

I have come to the point where I have

```
<option>9600</option> //wanted line
<scan:YResolution>9600</scan:YResolution> //unwanted line
<option>19200</option> //wanted line
<scan:YResolution>19200</scan:YResolution> //unwanted line
```

so I am trying to find a way to easily recursively eliminate the unwanted lines, and keep the wanted lines, not just the xml start and end tags but the values as well.

Anyone know an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: The best and easiest way would be via XSLT. Please provide sample of your input XML file, as well as desired output.

Comment: I did that pretty much. 

'<option>9600</option> //wanted line
<scan:YResolution>9600</scan:YResolution> //unwanted line
<option>19200</option> //wanted line
<scan:YResolution>19200</scan:YResolution> //unwanted line'

Meaning
input
'<option>9600</option>
<scan:YResolution>9600</scan:YResolution>
<option>19200</option>
<scan:YResolution>19200</scan:YResolution>'

Desired output
`<option>9600</option>
<option>19200</option>`

Comment: Getting formatting right on previous comment

I did that pretty much. 

`<option>9600</option> //wanted line
<scan:YResolution>9600</scan:YResolution> //unwanted line
<option>19200</option> //wanted line
<scan:YResolution>19200</scan:YResolution> //unwanted line`

Meaning
input

`<option>9600</option>
<scan:YResolution>9600</scan:YResolution>
<option>19200</option>
<scan:YResolution>19200</scan:YResolution>`

Desired output
`<option>9600</option>
<option>19200</option>`

Comment: Please delete both of your comments, and put everything into your question

Answer (score 0):

Your input file is not a well-formed XML file. That's why as mentioned:

> it seems it does not work with PHPs xml tools very well

I added a root with a namespace to make the input file a legitimate well-formed XML file.

The XSLT below is following a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<root xmlns:scan="url">
    <option>9600</option>
    <scan:YResolution>9600</scan:YResolution>
    <option>19200</option>
    <scan:YResolution>19200</scan:YResolution>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:scan="url">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="scan:YResolution"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root xmlns:scan="url">
  <option>9600</option>
  <option>19200</option>
</root>
```